# position a tooltip over a table cell with translate() in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a table from json data & d3, as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/rpardee/ku3q6txw/41/

I'm using mouseenter with d3.mouse() to get the x,y coordinates of the mouse pointer but need to translate the coordinates I get back from .mouse() into pixel locations that I can feed into translate() so as to properly place the tooltip.  So far my flailing has resulted in:

```
    // Move the tooltip over to where the mouse pointer is
    // There has *got* to be a better way of doing this.
    const coords = d3.mouse(this);
    const xpos = table._groups[0][0].clientWidth - coords[0] ;
    const ypos = table._groups[0][0].clientHeight - coords[1] ; ;
    imp_tooltip.style("transform", `translate(${xpos}px, ${ypos}px)`) ;
```

Which is close, but not close enough.

I'm guessing there's a d3.scaleLinear() that I can set up to do this translation, but I'm stymied trying to figure out what to feed into the .domain() & range() methods on that guy.

Can anybody throw me a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse's position can be retrieved with `d3.event.pageX` and `d3.event.pageY` ([reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#event)). These coordinates can then be used directly for the translation:

```
// Move the tooltip over to where the mouse pointer is
const xpos = d3.event.pageX ;
const ypos = d3.event.pageY ;
imp_tooltip.style("transform", `translate(${xpos}px, ${ypos}px)`) ;
```

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mohgpr2c/1/